# Kestrel address binding errors in azure app service

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have an aspnet core 2.2 app which looks like this:

```
return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
    {
        var env = builderContext.HostingEnvironment;

        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
    })
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseKestrel(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(opts =>
        {
            opts.ServerCertificate = GetCertificate();
            opts.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate;
            opts.ClientCertificateValidation = CertificateValidator.DisableChannelValidation;
        });
    });
```

Everything works great locally. However, when deployed to an azure app service I get the following:

`Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://127.0.0.1:5000: address already in use`

Is there anything special I need to do differently here? I don't particularly care about using Kestrel vs anything else as long as I can perform client certificate authentication (which works locally in my current implementation).

Answer (score 3):

The issue turned out to be that the application was already running but was not taking requests due to trying to use kestrel in the azure app service. I had to use `.UseIIS()` to get it to work. Perhaps I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know what port your app. will consistenly use, it may make sense to just code this into your app with `UseUrls`:

```
.UseUrls(urls: "http://localhost:10000")
```

Or running `dotnet run --urls="http://localhost:10000"` like this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2001).