# How to solve "Failed to bind to address http://127.0.0.1:5000: address already in use."

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core

I created a Asp.Net Core app with Visual Studio and used the publish option of VS to publish my app on my Azure account.

After publishing it, I used the link to access my website but I get a "HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start"

I went to the console in Azure to manually start my app and have more detail about the issue and I got this. [image: error on console]

Not really sure how to solve this issue with my port

Below is the code from program.cs

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("LocalConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<LotharDataBaseContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Comment: It usually happens when you already have an instance running, which is using that port.

Comment: Somewhere, a service has started on localhost with the Port 5000 already. That's why. It might be another instance of your App or Web Service, or another application on your machine using Port 5000. Specify other port, like 5001, 5050, 6000, or close that other service using port 5000.

Comment: That doesn't look like an Azure URL, what kind of deployment is this?

Comment: Is it running against localhost? If it is, you can run `netstat -apo` in `cmd` to check what applications might be using the port you're trying to run your code against. 
Also, if it  _is_ localhost, you're not gaining much by censoring it :)

Comment: @EricWu Obviously, the op is using the azure app service, so this solution is useless for him. Your method is suitable for use in vm or locally.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I will try first to change the port like @KeitelDOG suggested and see what happens

Comment: Did you fix this? Do you remember what you did?

Answer (score 1):

Through your screenshot, I saw Kestrel, so I think, the webapp you created should be on linux platform. The port occupancy on your screenshot is expected behavior, it shouldn't be the root cause. Since the site is already running, and you manually command it to start again, this error should appear.

I suggest you provide your Program.cs file first, we need to look at UseUrls, or the code for UseKestrel.

**How to check the logs when start webapp:**

1. open you kudu site, url should be `https://your_app_name.scm.azurewebsites.net`
2. open newui, `https://your_app_name.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui`
3. steps:

[image]

[image]

[image]

4. In this default_docker.log file, we will get useful message.

#### Steps you can try:

1. Try to add `.UseIIS`, and we know your platform is linux.

   [Kestrel address binding errors in azure app service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57116276/7687666)
2. Remove `.UseUrls()`, and re-deploy your webapp.

Comment: In program.cs I do not even have UseUrls(), instead I have UseHsts(). I will try your method.

Comment: I've added the code from program.cs

Comment: @Adriel Pls follow my steps to get the docker_logs in kudu site. Your program.cs file seems correct.

Comment: Hey Jason, I do not have a "...docker.log" file in my Kudu site. I can add a screenshot of what I have in logfiles

Comment: @Adriel Can you check the value of `GetConnectionString("LocalConnection")`.

Comment: @Adriel pls hide sensitive info.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was using the azure sql database so changing the connection string of database to use tcp protocol and 1433 as port, resolved this problem.
e-g

```
Server=tcp:<ServerName>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<DatabaseName>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when I tried to host **two** resources within the same `App Service Plan`, there was an app function that works perfectly within the `App Service Plan` when I added another Dotnet 6 webjob to the same Plan, even though the webjob was working in another plan peacefully, it wouldn't work any more, and it gives me the following error:

`Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://127.0.0.1:5000: address already in use.`

**#Solution**

so I tried to change the webjob port by adding this

```
ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://localhost:5001
```

[image]

in the `appsettings`, saved it then restarted the web app, and it magically worked.

Still not sure what causes the problem, It appears it is a Dotnet 6 webjob specific problem.